# AVFoundation AVAudioPlayer stop is pausing - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

It's fairly hard to show code for this as it is not noticeable in the code. I have some actions like `-(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender;` and `-(IBAction)PlaySound2:(id)sender;` and audio files. I have the sounds working all fine. I also have `-(void)Stop;`. When Play sound 1 is pressed it calls the method Stop and stops sound 2. and the same with sound 2.

The problem I am encountering is when you play sound 1 and stop sound 2, when you play sound 2 it starts from where it left off.

Inside my (void) I have `[PlaySound1 stop] //and [PlaySound2 stop]`

If anyone could help that would be great. If something was unclear, just comment on this and I'll try and explain it better.

Thanks :)

Comment: are you using multiple avplayers? how do you play sound1 and sound2?

Comment: I am using multiple yes. Is there a way to do it with 1 player but able to play multiple sound files? Currently I am using the IBActions for each buttons and inside the methods I'm using [PlaySound1 play] and [PlaySound2 play]

Comment: yes, you can use one AVPlayer, as you dont need to retain the position of each track you can replace the sound with something like  [AVPlayer replaceCurrentItemWithPlayerItem:playerItem] and then play it

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone for there help. Issue is now sorted. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping an **AVAudioPlayer** does not reset the play head.

> The stop method does not reset the value of the currentTime property to 0. In other words, if you call stop during playback and then call play, playback resumes at the point where it left off.

To resume playback from the start set the **currentTime** property to 0.0 before calling play.

example -

```
playSound2.currentTime = 0.0;
[playSound2 play];
```